# How do I inject a URL with ArquillianResource?

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to inject the URL in a simple standalone "hello world" test with Arquillian Drone/Graphene. Maybe I have missed something obvious but I can't find any documentation about this.

I'm thinking that there might be some system.properties (or arquillian.xml) that I can set like this:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <arq.extension.graphene.xxx>http://www.google.com</arq.extension.graphene.xxx>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

This is my simple test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DummyTest
{
    @Drone
    GrapheneSelenium browser;

    @ArquillianResource
    URL url;

//    URL url = URLUtils.buildUrl("http://www.google.com/");

   @Test
   public void openBrowser()
   {
      browser.open(url);
   }
}
```

And here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   
    <properties>
        <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
        <version.arquillian_core>1.0.4.Final</version.arquillian_core>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.arquillian_core}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-graphene</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>arquillian-tutorial</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it failing to inject? Or are you seeing a different URL? URLs injected by Arquillian either reflect the location of the web content root of a WAR/JAR deployments (or IIRC the location of the server for EAR deployments). And if you dont have a deployment or a server, then you'll find that the injected value is null. There may be ways to make it work, but that might depend on the container you use.

Comment: Yes it is failing to inject, java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup value for field java.net.URL org.arquillian.example.DummyTest.url. I'm not using a container because I'm only interested in driving Selenium with Drone/Graphene against a non java application.

Comment: In such case you can't use @@ArquillianResource injection. It's intended to be used by resource provider which is looking for the deployment url. If you are not using deployment at all I think simple @@BeforeClass where you do simple system property lookup will do the job. Does it sound good?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`URL` injection only works in a client deployment, so you need to mark your test `@RunAsClient`.  Alternatively it can be injected into any `@Test` method that is marked `@RunAsClient` as a parameter to the test.

Comment: OK so I can't use the annotation as I thought. John, you mention that I can inject the URL (or anything I guess) into a test if I annotate with @RunAsClient. Do you have an example of that? I know the solution that Bartosz suggest above but I was hoping for a more "elegant" solution

Comment: Add `@RunAsClient` on your `@Test` method, and it should work.  This is how drone is meant to operate.